# How can I replace the opening and closing h1 tags in a string using PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have captured the `<h1>` tag and its inner contents from a webpage and I need to remove the `<h1>` and `</h1>` parts of the string. The problem is that I won't know if the tag is written as `<h1>` or `<h1 id="something">`, etc. I know I can write

```
$tag = str_replace("<h1>", '', $tag);
$tag = str_replace("</h1>", '', $tag);
```

But how can I handle the more general case, where it may be `<h1 id="something">`, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `strip_tags` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I'm a newbie.